# html+input type text with regex not taking underscore(_) and special characters

Tags: html, regex

am working for an html input type text which i dont want to take underscore and special characters.
I dont want to have an change function which will do the same..if there is a regex which wont take mainly underscore and special characters will be awesome.

Any fiddle will be highly helpful

Comment: refer this https://jsfiddle.net/pmw57/2zqcqpzx/

Comment: fiddle is not working. am not searching for a onChange function,if any regex for the same input type,will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this replace method

```js
function validate(event){
  var checkRegexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;
  var replaceRegexp = /[^A-Z0-9]+/ig;
  var getVal = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if (getVal.search(checkRegexp) === -1){ 
    var newVal = getVal.replace(replaceRegexp, "");
    document.getElementById("username").value = newVal;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="username" required onkeyup="validate()">
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```